# trouble to comsume POST service in form-data with fetch and axios not work.... with react native status 406

Tags: react-native, fetch, postman, axios

I am programming a react native application that consumes services, when the service is consumed with POSTMAN if it works when sending the header and body, however when I try to consume with fetch and axios of react native it returns me status 406 does not return any other response , I do not know if I'm omitting something or this something man in my function thanks [postman consume](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IyAs4.jpg) [postman body status 200](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fYr0M.jpg) [fetch function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y4mrs.jpg) or [axios function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AapW0.jpg) [packagejson](https://i.stack.imgur.com/44Z6J.jpg)

```
INSIDE POSTMAN:
(key :value)
Headers: 
X-Api-Key: 123456754321345 
Body:
username: a@b.com
password: password

and the service return

{
    "status": true,
    "message": "Login succeed",
    "data": {
        "id": "3",
        "email": "a@b.com",
        "oauth_uid": null,
        "oauth_provider": null,
        "pass": "4f06434a830e21146a8ce3444fee870a60cb1ebb92871589c6f5bc8a22284925",
        "username": "username",
        "full_name": "Nombre Apellido",
        "avatar": "20180806212239-74-512.png",
        "banned": "0",
        "last_login": "2018-08-17 21:32:06",
        "last_activity": null,
        "date_created": "2018-08-06 21:22:39",
        "forgot_exp": null,
        "remember_time": null,
        "remember_exp": null,
        "verification_code": null,
        "top_secret": null,
        "ip_address": "186.3.71.211",
        "puntoventa": "",
        "idciudad": "0",
        "idsector": "0",
        "direccion": "",
        "latitud": null,
        "longitud": null,
        "telefono": null,
        "idcliente": "0"
    },
    "token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJkYXRhIjp7ImlkIjoiMyJ9LCJpYXQiOjE1MzQ1NTk1MjcsImV4cCI6MTUzNDU4MTEyN30.Tbs9MYIu8hR-TDjxnUlHs8j64JoXquRJYD04AUvZNmu4"
}

IN REACT NATIVE:
INSIDE package-json

"dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "^4.0.0",
    "eslint": "^5.3.0",
    "native-base": "^2.7.2",
    "react": "16.4.1",
    "react-native": "^0.55.4",
    "react-navigation": "^2.8.0"
  },

inside Login.js

 componentDidMount() {
this.getLogin(); 
}

FETCH FUNCTION:
getLogin = () => {
  const formdata = new FormData();
  formdata.append('username', 'a@b.com');
  formdata.append('password', 'password');

  fetch("http://url/api/user/login", {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'X-Api-Key': '123456754321345'
        },
        body: formdata
    })
        .then(response => {
            console.log(
                'response', response
            );
        })
        .done();
  };

------------------------
OR WITH AXIOS
 componentDidMount() {
this.getLogin2(); 
}

AXIOS FUNCTION

-------------------//I TRIED WITH BOTH WITHOUT RESULT
getLogin2 = () => {

  let formData = new FormData();
  formData.append("usuario", 'prueba@yopmail.com');
  formData.append("password", 'prueba1');
  console.log('data form', formData);
  const config = {
    headers: {
      'X-Api-Key': '2C36AB90F09F447D3633DB75812C30A3'
     }
  };

  axios.post('http://gestiona-desarrollo.000webhostapp.com/api/user/login', formData, config).then(
    response => {
      console.log({ response });
    },
    error => {
      console.log({ error });
    }
  );
}
```

In both case when i run debug mode the status is 406 for both options

Comment: Can you please do not show images, instead of this format this as code snippet or whatever better readable? It is better then to help you (e.g. copy/pasting snippets instead of writing it).

Comment: sure... i update the q thanks